# What does "matriculation" refer to?

Tags: united-states, europe, terminology

In the US and Europe, what does a University mean when they ask for grades from Matriculation?

Is it the 10th grade or the 12th grade or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it is simply referring to the official record of grades as provided by an institution. "Matriculation" is the act of officially joining some organization. It isn't about grade level at all. But most places want to see grades from all prior education no matter what the level. So, if this is about university applications it means official secondary (high) school grades. For graduate study, you may not need secondary school grades but all college level grades.

The typical process is to have them sent directly by the institution, rather than your own copies.